# Azure Web App - Error deploying python (django) application

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy, azure-deployment

I'm trying to deploy using the github actions from this repository:
https://github.com/ViniciusDevelopment/test-deployment

which is basically a modification of the standard project made available by Microsoft for testing and learning([link azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=django%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli%2Cvscode-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azportal%2Cterminal-bash%2Cdeploy-instructions-zip-azcli)):

```
git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart
```

The base project provided by the corporation performed well. However, when adding another app and executing the commit, several errors occur, from gateway to error 500

the log stream didn't give me any relevant information

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you able to run locally without any issues.

Comment: Yes, it just doesn't run on Azure

Comment: Server 500 error occurs only when there is an issue within the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code, made some changes, and was able to deploy it to Azure without any issues.

Ensure your `wsgi.py` correctly sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to 'Quickproject.settings' and ensure your project structure is consistent. Make sure your packages are up to date.

**Settings.py**:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = '1234567890'
DEBUG = True
APPEND_SLASH = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'hello_azure',
    'AppPlanEx',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    # Add whitenoise middleware after the security middleware
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'quickstartproject.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'quickstartproject.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

**quickstartproject/urls.py:**

```py
from  django.contrib  import  admin
from  django.urls  import  include, path
from  quickstartproject  import  settings
from  django.conf.urls.static  import  static
urlpatterns  = [
path('', include('hello_azure.urls')),
path('appplanex/', include('AppPlanEx.urls')),
path('ttt/', include('hello_azure.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]  
if  settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns  +=  static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**hello_azure/urls.py:**

```py
from  django.urls  import  path
from . import  views
from  quickstartproject  import  settings
from  django.conf.urls.static  import  static
urlpatterns  = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('hello/', views.hello, name='hello'),
]
if  settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns  +=  static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**hello_azure/views.py:**

```py
from  django.shortcuts  import  render, redirect
from  django.http  import  HttpResponse
from  django.views.decorators.csrf  import  csrf_exempt 
def  index(request):
print('Request for index page received')
return  render(request, 'hello_azure/index.html') 
@csrf_exempt
def  hello(request):
if  request.method ==  'POST':
name  =  request.POST.get('name')
if  name  is  None  or  name  ==  '':
print("Request for hello page received with no name -- redirecting")
return  redirect('index')
else:
print("Request for hello page received with name=%s"  %  name)
context  = {'name': name }
return  render(request, 'hello_azure/hello.html', context)
else:
return  redirect('index')
```

**AppPlanEx/urls.py**:

```
from  django.urls  import  path
from . import  views
from  quickstartproject  import  settings
from  django.conf.urls.static  import  static
urlpatterns  = [
path('', views.Home, name="Home"),
path('appplanex/', views.Home, name="appplanex"),
]
if  settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns  +=  static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Here's the local Output:

[image]

[image]

After making the above changes to your code, I was able to deploy the app to Azure App Service using GitHub Actions successfully.

Here's the output:

[image]

[image]